# Wrong behavior of map box gl with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

When I change the position of the map, it returns to its original position. How to remove this behavior? I need that when changing the position of the map, the map remains in the same position.

Wrong behavior GIF
https://gyazo.com/4fa3cf138ceacc1ffdb4cb9055f8b8f3

```js
 <Map
          dragRotate={false}
          scrollZoom={true}
          zoom={[15]}
          center={[23.924760, 54.930400]}
          style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
          containerStyle={{
            height: "500px",
            width: "100wv"
          }}>
          <ZoomControl/>
          <a href='https://goo.gl/maps/kPEmoBpFUPL2' className='link-primary map-link' target='_blank'>Directions</a>
          <Layer
            type="symbol"
            id="marker"
            layout={{ "icon-image": "harbor-15" }}>
            <Feature
              coordinates={[23.925960, 54.930854]}
            />
          </Layer>
        </Map>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user moves the map, you just need to update the map state to record the new map position (lat/lng, zoom...). For example:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4M29iazA2Z2gycXA4N2pmbDZmangifQ.-g_vE53SD2WrJ6tFX7QHmA';

class Application extends React.Component {

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lng: 5,
      lat: 34,
      zoom: 1.5
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { lng, lat, zoom } = this.state;
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom
    });

    map.on('move', () => {
      const { lng, lat } = map.getCenter();
      this.setState({
        lng: lng.toFixed(4),
        lat: lat.toFixed(4),
        zoom: map.getZoom().toFixed(2)
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { lng, lat, zoom } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="inline-block absolute top left mt12 ml12 bg-darken75 color-white z1 py6 px12 round-full txt-s txt-bold">
          <div>{`Longitude: ${lng} Latitude: ${lat} Zoom: ${zoom}`}</div>
        </div>
        <div ref={el => this.mapContainer = el} className="absolute top right left bottom" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

For a full-fledged example, check out their [basic boilerplate on Github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-react-examples/tree/master/basic).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the **useState** hook to bind the **center** and **zoom** props with a state and it will keep them unchanged without the need to update the values on every interaction. See: https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/issues/81

The only downside I found is that you need to wrap the zoom on an array to keep the equality...

```js
  const [center, setCenter] = useState<[number, number]>([-94.239, 36.066]);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState<[number]>([11]);
...
  <Map
    style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
    center={center}
    zoom={zoom}
  >
...
```